# assert as an IOT in BigchainDB

Tags: iot, bigchaindb

We are working on a project which requires an IOT sensors to be connected Blockchain. I am unable to figure out how should I connect the sensor to BigchainDB and how can read the data.

Answer (score 0):

For now, you can:

1. Sign up for an account on the BigchainDB Testnet: https://testnet.bigchaindb.com/
2. Write some software that takes the data from your IOT sensor, puts it inside a BigchainDB transaction, and sends that transaction to the BigchainDB Testnet. You can use one of the BigchainDB drivers (software libraries / SDKs) to help you with that. See https://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/latest/drivers-clients/index.html
3. You can also write software to query and read information from the BigchainDB Testnet using the same driver.

Comment: Can we directly link the IOT device to the BigchainDB?

Comment: Some software has to take the data from the IOT device, put it in a BigchainDB transaction, and send that transaction to a BigchainDB network (as an HTTP request).

Comment: We are planning to write a python code which invokes the transfer transaction with the change in the IOT sensor measurements.